# Select data from multiple tables using primary key (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

**Here's my structure:**

```
darkrp_player:
uid (Primary Key)
wallet

playerinformation:
uid (Foreign key to darkrp_player/primary key to display)
steamID

display:
uid (foreign key to darkrp_player + playerinformation)
steamID
wallet
```

Basically, i want the steamID from playerinformation and wallet from darkrp_player to be transferred to display using uid. I dont really know SQL so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: what did you try so far? Got any errors?

Comment: I didnt get any errors just blank

Answer (score 2):

You can select from multiple tables using JOIN. Below is an example of selecting the wallet and steamID using uid from the tables you provided,

```
SELECT p.wallet, i.steamID 
FROM darkrp_player p
LEFT JOIN playerinformation i ON i.uid = p.uid;
```

(I'm aliasing darkrp_player with p and playerinformation with i.)

It sounds like you want to take the uid, steamID, and wallet and insert it into the the display table. You can do that like this:

```
INSERT INTO display (uid, steamID, wallet)
SELECT p.uid, p.wallet, i.steamID 
FROM darkrp_player p
LEFT JOIN playerinformation i ON i.uid = p.uid;
```

Comment: It only gets 1 set and an error: " #1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you just want to join the data when you speak of "transfer", you can simply join the tables:

```
SELECT playerinformation.uid, steamID, wallet    
FROM darkrp_player  
INNER JOIN playerinformation ON playerinformation.uid = darkrp_player.uid;
```

Comment: That queries it correctly, however it doesn't store that info into display.

Comment: Yes, it seems I misunderstood your intent after all. See Claudio's answer above for storing this into a table.